# The 'Query' and the 'InputFile' options are mutually exclusive. when using Azure SQL Database Deployment task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools

I am working with the Azure SQL Database Deployment task `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` in Azure DevOps and getting the below error:

`##[error]The 'Query' and the 'InputFile' options are mutually exclusive.`

I am not using the `-Query` flag in the configuration, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was passing in both `additionalArguments:` **AND** `sqlAdditionalArguments:` to the DevOps task - the mutual exclusivity is on these parameters on the task.

After consolidating my parameters into one of these, my deployment task now works.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm not following you when you said you consolidated them. Where did you do it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kevin, been a while since I did this, but I believe what I was getting at with the answer was that all additional arguments should be passed into the task with only one of the above parameters. If you're hitting this error, re-format your `additionalArguments` as `sqlAdditionalArguments` (or the other way around), pass them all in as one parameter, and that should solve it. 
If you're still facing issues, please share the details of the task as is after removing any sensitive info and I can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I received this same error (The 'Query' and the 'InputFile' options are mutually exclusive.) when trying to run Invoke-Sqlcmd from a PowerShell task in Azure DevOps release pipeline. For me, it turned out that using the -Encrypt parameter was the problem. I removed that from the PS command to resolve the issue.